# What architectural features will allow this microprocessor to access a separate "I/O space"?

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems, cpu

I'm studying for my final and don't understand this question.  Here is the full question (from Stallings 8th edition):

> Consider a hypothetical microprocessor generating a 16-bit address
>   (e.g., assume the program counter and the address registers are 16
>   bits wide) and having a 16-bit data bus.
>
> a. What is the maximum memory address space that the processor can
>   access directly if it is connected to a “16-bit memory”?
>
> b. What is the maximum memory address space that the processor can
>   access directly if it is connected to an “8-bit memory”?
>
> **c. What architectural features will allow this microprocessor to
>   access a separate “I/O space”?**
>
> d. If an input and an output instruction can specify an 8-bit I/O
>   port number, how many 8-bit I/O ports can the microprocessor support?
>   How many 16-bit I/O ports? Explain.

If I'm following, the answer to "a" is the processor is generating 2^16 = 64 Kbytes and the bus is 16-bit so the answer it 64 Kbytes.

However, for "b", the answer is 64 Kbytes are being generated but since the bus is only 8-bit, it requires twice as many cycles.

For the answer to "c", I am clueless and I think that carries over into me being clueless on "d". :-\

Comment: for part c I think the answer could be the use of an expansion bus

Comment: An 8086 processor with 16 bit PC and address registers could access 2^20 + 2^16 bytes of memory.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU uses the same address/data bus to access both the memory space and the I/O space. They are however distinguished by an extra signal that tells whether the address/data is in the memory space or the I/O space. For instance, in x86 this signal is called $M/\overline{IO}$ (pin 28).

Comment: Thanks @ran-g  If the pin is "high" (meaning "set to 1"), it will know the data is in the I/O space?  If it is "low" (meaning "set to 0"), it will know the data is in the memory space?  (Are my responses to "a" and "b" correct?)

Comment: the notation $M/\overline{IO}$ means $=1$ for memory and $=0$ for IO.

Answer (score 0):

(For a) & b), my take is $2^{16}$ of whatever are *addressable units* - the bus size *not* being an indication (see e.g. Intel 8086↔8088). It does not read *16 address lines/signals*, nor does it mention *address multiplexing*.
Implementations *not* supplying a signal for every architectural address bit are somewhat common: *physical* address space may be smaller (or, historically, larger) than the *architectural* address space.)

c) In the programming model, the pivotal feature is existence of *I/O instructions* mentioned in d). Which does not specify whether there are separate instructions for 8-bit and 16-bit ports.
d) assuming no separate instructions for accessing 8-bit and 16-bit ports, both share "an 8-bit address space".